# android datePicker with different API

Tags: android, api, datepicker

In my android app I created a datepicker, the problem is if my application is running on the emulator "Nexus api 23" the result is the following:

[image: image: DatePicker in Nexus API 23]

If my application is running on my phone Note 1 with API 16 the result is like the following:

[image: image: DatePicker in Note with api 16]

Comment: API 23 using appcompat theme (Material)

Comment: DatePicker theme is different as per API. If you want same DatePicker for all version then create custom DatePicker.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya so is it a solution  to do as the first picture always?

Comment: @AmolSawant96Kuli as I can do that?

Comment: @AbdAlah You can use 23 .

Comment: I created a TimeClock when I want to get the hours and minutes I have a problem help me please

Answer (score 0):

Did you accomplish to this problem?